# Is it possible to run node.js natively in the VSCode Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I saw the project https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-nodebook which allows to run node.js code in Jupyter Notebook, but I am interested in native integration: just create a file, open it, chose the kernel and work.